# Multiple directives asking for templates on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="border:1px solid; height:300px; width:500px; position:relative;  left:100px" id="canvas">
  <tbox ng-repeat="tb in textBoxes" ng-model="tb">
  </tbox>
</div>
```

And the following 2 directives

```js
appModule.directive('resizable', function($compile, $document) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: '<div ng-style="{top:tb.x, left:tb.y, height:tb.height, width:tb.width}"  ng-transclude><span class="scale">s</span></div>',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    require: 'ngModel'
  }
});

appModule.directive('tbox', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<div class="editbox" resizable editoptions>{{tb.text}}</div>',
    replace: true
  }
});
```

What exactly does the following error that angular is throwing me means?

```
Error: Multiple directives [tbox, resizable] asking for template on: <div class="editbox" resizable="" editoptions="" ng-repeat="tb in textBoxes" ng-model="tb">
```

jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/sEZM3/

Comment: If you're up for creating a Plunker, I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Both of your directives define a template. Angular doesn't know which template to use. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @JedidiahHurt, please see the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sEZM3/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40782709/842386 might be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 30):

Both of your directives are trying to replace the element in the dom.  Try removing the the `replace: true` lines in your directive definition object.

Comment: removing replace doesn't help

Answer (score 29):

The same error may occur if you try to load the same directive code more than once by mistake. It may happen especially when you keep every Angular item (like directive) in separate file and you include every single one with separate  line. That was my case.

Comment: Or somebody forget to rename directive name

Comment: This was it for me. Copy/pasted some directive boilerplate and forgot to change the directive's name.

Comment: Having them duplicated in index.html, for example

Answer (score 15):

For me, this was caused by multiple copies of the directive and template existing in the *dist* directory caused by grunt building without cleaning (during a *watch* task). A clean and rebuild solved this for me.

Comment: even I had the same issue, my temp folder (from where I serve) had two copies of the same directive. deleted one and it got fixed.

Comment: I should be able to upvote this twice as it has saved me yet again!

Answer (score 8):

For me it was including the same directive twice in the index.html.

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me when I was having two components with the same name (copy paste error):

For my coffeescript, but easy to happen in pure angular:

```
component1.coffee
    appModule.component('name', {
    templateUrl: '/public/partials/html1.html',
  controller: 'controler1',
  bindings: {
    somebindings: '<'
  }
});


component2.coffee
    appModule.component('name', {
    templateUrl: '/public/partials/html2.html',
  controller: 'controler2',
  bindings: {
    somebindings: '<'
  }
});
```

Conclusion: "name" has to be unique in whole app.

Answer (score 4):

For Visual Studio users using TypeScript, this got me. I'd renamed my typescript file and the built .js file was in the directory (but it doesn't show up in the project). I had to show all files in the directory to remove the lingering unused *.js files.

Answer (score 2):

The *resizable* directive is incorrect. The `ng-transclude` directive must be applied to the innermost element, because its content will be discarded and replaced with transcluded content.

You should surround *tbox* directive template with (corrected) *resizable* element directive. I dont' know what *editoptions* attribute does, but if it's also a directive, then it also shouldn't have a template.

I mean something like this:

```
appModule.directive('resizable', function($compile, $document) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div ng-style="{top:tb.x, left:tb.y, height:tb.height, width:tb.width}"  ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        //...

appModule.directive('tbox', function($document) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<resizable><div class="editbox" editoptions>{{tb.text}}</div></resizable>',
        replace: true,
        //...
```

Result:

```
<div ng-style="{top:tb.x, left:tb.y, height:tb.height, width:tb.width}"  ng-transclude>
    <div class="editbox" editoptions>{{tb.text}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Adam, essentially my aim is to create smaller manageable directives and combine them into larger directives. Regarding the ng-transclude, what I really wanna do is to wrap the template around the current existing dom element that has the resizable attribute. What would be the remedy?

Comment: "Transclusion works only for element directives (restrict: 'E')" - that's not true.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t have one (element) directive *directly* referencing another (element) directive. Wrap it with a `<div>`, e.g:

```
template: '<div><my-custom-directive>'
        + '</my-custom-directive></div>'
```

See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5428 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a reference to a missing file in the BundleConfig, I removed the reference and it started to work.

Comment: In my case, I had a script in two separate bundles and on this page both bundles were being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

For me there were no duplicates in my code.  This happend as a result of me duplicating a module to get a headstart on the new one, and then doing a module wide find/replace and changing the names of the files.

Even though there was no duplicate anymore, and I stopped and started the browsersync based server, the error continued.

Resolving it was done by removing the .tmp directory that the build system was creating for the dev environment.

Evidently the FountainJS generator I'm using creates a build system that leaves the .tmp directory dirty in some cases like this.  It's caught me a few times now.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be a simple mistake like keeping both `template` and `templateUrl` properties in the same directive.

Answer (score 0):

(in case it helps someone else)

For me the issue was having a backup file (i.e. .bkp.html) which was just an old copy of a template I was using for reference - but this was being included by karma since it matched the ".../**/*.html" pattern.

Answer (score -2):

importing same directive more than one time can cause this issue.

Comment: You are contradicting the reason why directive concept was made