# Custom AngularJS attribute inside the directive with HTML page template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to create two directives: one of them should be an simple tag and another one should be an attribute for this tag.
Another words I want to make something like this:

```
<outer inner></outer>
```

Here is my HTML layout:

```
<!-- Some not interesting stuff here -->

<body ng-app="app">
    <outer inner></outer>
</body>

<!-- and here -->
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('inner', function() {
    return {
        require: "outer",
        template: "<div></div>",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.say = function() {
                console.log('Inner controller...');
            };

            $scope.foo = function() {};

            $scope.say();       
        },  
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('Inner link...');
        }
    };
});


app.directive('outer', function() {   
    return {        
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            mes : "="
        },
        controller: function($scope) {

            $scope.message = "";

            $scope.sayAgain = function() {
                console.log('Outer controller...');
            };

            $scope.getMessage = function() {

              console.log($scope.message);

        };            

            $scope.sayAgain();
        },
        transclude: false,
        template: "<div>{{sayAgain()}}</div>",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log(scope);
        }   
    };
});
```

The problem is that I want to have hidden HTML template for my attribute (`inner` element).
But when I try to run this construction `<outer inner></outer>` I got this message:

```
Error: Multiple directives [outer, inner] asking for template on: <outer inner="" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at O (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:49:506)
    at A (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:46:39)
    at W (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:40:256)
    at W (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:40:338)
    at y (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:39:7)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:16:276
    at Object.e.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:92:272)
    at Object.e.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:92:379)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:16:236
```

When I comment `template: "<div></div>"` in inner directive everything is OK.
I don't know how to avoid this obstacle... How to make everything in such a way the HTML will be stored and the main page will be rendered properly without any bugs?

Comment: The problem is you have two directives trying to insert a template into the same element.  Instead of making `inner` a directive you could just make it an attribute on the `outer` directive and use it appropriately in the `link` function

Comment: ya this has also been mentioned it the docs may be it provide more idea http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile:multidir?p0=one&p1=outer&p2=template&p3=%3Couter%3E

Comment: Ok, so I will make an attribute on the outer and put there my inner directive. But what should I do in link function of outer? How to use logic implemented in inner directive?

Comment: Possible repetition of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801467/angular-multiple-directives-asking-for-templates-on