# Angularjs Multiple directives [gridsection, gridsection] asking for template on: <div gridsection="">

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm receiving the error: `Multiple directives [gridsection, gridsection] asking for templateon : <div gridsection="">` with this code.

I don't see how i'm using nested directives or what is causing this.

html page

```
<div gridsection ></div>
```

directive

```
angular.module('web').directive('gridsection', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,

        scope: {
      patient: "=patient"
        },
        templateUrl: 'directive/section.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {


        }
    };
});
```

directive/section.html

```
<div>
  here?
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like you are declaring the gridsection multiple times in your angular code.

Comment: You mean like i have it on multiple html elements?

Comment: I think that you have this line in two places,

angular.module('web').directive('gridsection', function() {});

Comment: Ahh you are right. I had imported it my index.html twice. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Or you could be including the source script twice.

Comment: I have seen this before when I have a copy of a directive script file in a folder. Doh!

Comment: The above comment should be an answer @Kildareflare

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this before when I have a copy of a directive script file in a folder.

i.e. my file structure was

```
* myDirective.js
* myDirective - copy.js
```

So essentially I had two directives with the same name.

**Doh!**

> Note originally posted this as a comment but created as an answer in response to comment from @jayjayjay

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I was getting this exception because I was trying to create a directive named `pager` and that was colliding with Bootstrap's pager.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't include the script tag twice.

I had this issue but only declared the directive once in the markup, turns out it was because I included the script twice.

Note: I saw this in one of the comments for another answer and posted it as an answer for easier access/to prevent it getting lost.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error for a reason not specified in other answers.
I was using declaration for xyz directive as `<xyz xyz="xyz"></xyz>`

my definition was:

```
  angular.module('app')
  .directive('xyz', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: '..../xyz.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        xyz: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    };
  });
```

The problem here is that I allowed directive to be used as element and attribute. so `<xyz xyz="xyz"></xyz>` contained both the declaration which was causing the issue.

**Solution is to either restrict the directive to be used as Element only `restrict: 'E'` OR change the name of the directive to something like xyzView and use it like `<xyz-view xyz="xyz"></xyz-view>`.**

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I was including the directive in a script file and also adding it dynamically using $compileProvider.directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider).

I was moving from a dynamic loading system to just having eveything packaged ina bundle. Once I removed the dynamic compile it all worked as expected.