# AngularJs Multiple directives asking for template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using carousel angular ui bootstrap as a directive but running into this issue:

> Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [carousel, carousel (module: myApp.common)] asking for template on: `<div ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()" class="carousel" ng-swipe-right="prev()" ng-swipe-left="next()">`

It's saying that I'm using many directives on the same DOM element which is untrue. I have had it checked in a blank page and still, the error message is being shown.

I'm using:

- "angular": "^1.5.0"
- "angular-animate": "^1.5.0",
- "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^0.14.3",

Check my code below:
carousel.js

```
'use strict';

var CarouselController = (function() {
  /*@ngInject*/
  function CarouselController() {
    this.myInterval = 5000;
    this.noWrapSlides = false;
    this.active = 0;

    var slides = this.slides = [];
    var currIndex = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      this.addSlide();
    }
  }

  CarouselController.prototype.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;

    slides.push({
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
      text: ['Nice image','Awesome photograph','That is so cool','I love that'][slides.length % 4],
      id: currIndex++
    });
  }

  CarouselController.prototype.randomize = function() {
    var indexes = this.generateIndexesArray();
    this.assignNewIndexesToSlides(indexes);
  }

  CarouselController.prototype.assignNewIndexesToSlides = function() {
    for (var i = 0, l = slides.length; i < l; i++) {
      slides[i].id = indexes.pop();
    }
  }

  CarouselController.prototype.generateIndexesArray = function() {
    var indexes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < currIndex; ++i) {
      indexes[i] = i;
    }
    return this.shuffle(indexes);
  }

  CarouselController.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var tmp, current, top = array.length;

    if (top) {
      while (--top) {
        current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
        tmp = array[current];
        array[current] = array[top];
        array[top] = tmp;
      }
    }

    return array;
  }

  return CarouselController;
})();

var carousel = function() {

  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'app/common/carousel/carousel.html',
    controller: CarouselController,
    controllerAs: 'carousel'
  };
}

module.exports = carousel;
```

module.js

```
'use strict';

var angular   = require('angular');
var navbar    = require('./navbar/navbar');
var searchbar = require('./searchbar/searchbar');
var hotel     = require('./latest-hotels/latest-hotels');
var comment   = require('./comment/comment');
var carousel  = require('./carousel/carousel');

angular
  .module('myApp.common', [])
  .directive('navbar', navbar)
  .directive('searchbar', searchbar)
  .directive('latestHotel', hotel)
  .directive('comment', comment)
  .directive('carousel', carousel);
```

carousel.html:

```
<div style="height: 305px">
    <uib-carousel active="carousel.active" interval="carousel.myInterval" no-wrap="carousel.noWrapSlides">
        <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in carousel.slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>{{slide.text}}</h4>
            </div>      
        </uib-slide>
    </uib-carousel>
</div>
```

Any ideas is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide the source for your carousel directive. And from the message, it appears that you have two directives with the same name, but different modules. Almost certainly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801467/multiple-directives-asking-for-templates-on

Comment: No they are not the same. The solution there is not working for my case. And if you notice I have posted related codes already.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the the controller was linked to the directive at the bottom of that listing (needed to scroll).

Comment: Your carousel.html also uses a directive named slide. Where is the source for that?

Comment: Do you mean this `ng-repeat="slide in carousel.slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">`

Comment: Not the ng-repeat part as such. You are nesting a <uib-slide> within <uib-carousel>. Your problem is almost certainly to do with the interaction between them. We have the source for the carousel directive, but not for the slide. Also, I'm almost certain you'll need to use transclusion in some way, since you are specifying your slides as nodes nested within the carousel. I think the source for the slide directive will clear things up.

Comment: It seems like that's not a problem because I tried to test it on a new project, same those library versions, as a directive still, and it was running perfectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114197/discussion-between-cobus-kruger-and-lucky-lam).

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies because you have declared carousel directive twice, either intentionally, or unintentionally when you use gulp (or similar build system).
It can be happened because when you restructured your carousel directives to other folder, then gulp system that build/serve your code from /tmp or /dist folder still use the old carousel directive from previous build, while also generate a new carousel directive from your new restructured folder.

The solution is simple. Just remove your tmp or dist folder, and run your gulp to generate a fresh copy of files that served to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interaction between directives. Based on the message (Multiple directives [**carousel**, **carousel** (module: myApp.common)]), I think the most likely cause is your templateUrl.

Your HTML contains uib-carousel but is then used as the template for the carousel directive. So you are including carousel within itself recursively. And every nested one is trying to replace your div tag in the call site.

I think your carousel.html should look like this:

```
<uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in carousel.slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
  <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h4>{{slide.text}}</h4>
  </div>      
</uib-slide>
```

And your call site like this:

```
<div style="height: 305px">
    <uib-carousel active="carousel.active" 
        interval="carousel.myInterval" no-wrap="carousel.noWrapSlides" 
        ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()" class="carousel" 
        ng-swipe-right="prev()" ng-swipe-left="next()"></uib-carousel>
</div>
```

If you still get the error after this, I expect your slide controller also uses replace for its own template.

Comment: still not working. Do you want to have a look at my initial source code [link](https://github.com/LuckyLam34/HotelProject) this version doesn't include the carousel directive